# How to Get connaction string from configuration in a static class?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a class that I can get the connection string from the configuration

```cs
public class UserClass
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    public UserClass(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<UserClass> logger) => _configuration = configuration;

    public bool CheckUserPermissions(string email, string password, bool hashed, string SessionID)
    {
       string strConnString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection").ToString();
    }
}
```

In a static class, I can't get the configuration.

```cs
public static class FunctionClass
{
    
    public static DataTable GetData()
    {
       string strConnString =  configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection").ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you use a static class in the first place? Make it non-static, then make whatever code depends on it take it in via constructor injection. Are you familiar with how Dependency Injection works?

Answer (score 2):

You can't inject any service to the static classes. but if you need to access the connection string in a static class, You have two options:

1:

You can use `ConfigurationBuilder`:

```cs
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile(dir) // dir: path to the configuration file
            .Build();
var conStr = config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
```

2:

If it is an Asp.net core project, try to read the connection string in the startup class and set your connection string to a `static` global property/field.

```cs
public static class FunctionClass
{
   public static string ConnectionString = "";

// set the ConnectionString value in the startup
```